# Theta-logistic equation

Tags: dynamical-systems

[image]

[image]

I can't comprehend any of the solution for iii). WHy for $\theta=1$ do we have linear dependence of the growth on the population size?

Answer (score 1):

The author means that the growth *rate* is linear in $N_t$. That is, the equation has the general form
\begin{equation}
 \Delta N_t = R(N_t)\,N_t.
\end{equation}
If the rate $R(N_t)$ would be constant in $N_t$, we would have standard exponential growth. Now, the way the growth rate $R$ depends on $N_t$ is specified as
\begin{equation}
 R(N_t) = r \left(1-\left(\frac{N_t}{K}\right)^\theta\right).
\end{equation}
As you see, if $\theta = 0$, then $R$ is a linear function of $N_t$, so then the growth rate depends linearly on the population size.

Again, as in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762416/michels-menten-steady-state-hypothesis), a matter of sloppy wording.